# Configuration.GetSection() easily gets primitive string values but not complex values

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

This really amazes me. I am reading values from appsettings.json using `Configuration.GetSection` method and in nutshell my appsettings.json looks like below:

```
"AppSettings": 
  {  
    "PathPrefix": "",
    "Something": "Something else",
    "Clients":{"foo": "bar"}
  }
```

Now I surprises me is that if I do something like below:

```
var foo = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Clients:foo").Value;
```

Then it gets the value correctly. It gets the value `bar`

However, when I do

```
 var clients = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Clients").Value;
```

it returns null. It's not only this field, whenever I call `getSection` method to get any complex object then it returns null but when I call it to get a basic string value then it gets the value correctly **even though** seeminglyi, it had problems in getting its parent element. This baffles me and raises three questions:

1. Why would it have issues getting complex values but not getting basic string values?
2. Is it by design? If so , why?
3. If I want to load entire object, how do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can load an entire object using a strongly typed object.

First, create a class (or classes) to hold you settings. Based on your example this would look like:

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public string PathPrefix { get; set; }
    public string Something { get; set; }
    public Clients Clients { get; set; }
}

public class Clients
{
    public string foo { get; set; }
}
```

Now, you need to add the Options service to your service collection and load your settings from the configuration:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // This is only required for .NET Core 2.0
    services.AddOptions();

    services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

You now access the properties by injecting them into your class, for example:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly AppSettings _settings;

    public HomeController(IOptions<AppSettings> settings)
    {
        _settings = settings.Value;
    }
}
```

You can also load suboptions in the `ConfigureService` method by specifying the configuration section to load e.g.

```
services.Configure<Clients>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Clients");
```

Now you can inject `IOptions<Clients>` to access those settings

The official documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Answer (score 4):

What would you expect it to return? You can get complex objects using the `Get<T>` extension method. Try this:

```
var clients = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Clients").Get<YourClientsType>();
```